# How to remove metadata or prevent adding comment "Processed by SoX" using sox?

Tags: command-line, audio-conversion, sox

If you convert using sox, it adds a comment to the metadata:

```
$ soxi audio.wav

Input File     : 'audio.wav'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 48000
Precision      : 24-bit
Duration       : 00:00:04.20 = 201600 samples ~ 315 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 605k
Bit Rate       : 1.15M
Sample Encoding: 24-bit Signed Integer PCM

$ sox audio.wav audio.flac
$ soxi audio.flac

Input File     : 'audio.flac'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 48000
Precision      : 24-bit
Duration       : 00:00:04.20 = 201600 samples ~ 315 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 414k
Bit Rate       : 788k
Sample Encoding: 24-bit FLAC
Comment        : 'Comment=Processed by SoX'
```

How to prevent or remove that?

Answer (score 0):

`--comment ''` will prevent adding or remove an existing comment

```
sox audio.wav -comment '' audio.flac
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 48000
Precision      : 24-bit
Duration       : 00:00:04.20 = 201600 samples ~ 315 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 414k
Bit Rate       : 788k
Sample Encoding: 24-bit FLAC
```